# Properly Exporting Types in NPM Package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I've been trying to create an NPM package (not public), using Typescript, which will be usable by my company's Nodejs applications. I'm created a small proof of concept which just has some constants. But I cannot seem to figure out how to structure everything to make it importable and usable.

I want to use es2015 module syntax.

The tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["ES2015", "DOM"],                                        
    "module": "ES2015",                                
    "moduleResolution": "node",                     
    "declaration": true,                            
    "outDir": "./dist",                             
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",               
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        
    "skipLibCheck": true                            
  }
}
```

And the package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "packmodpoc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",  
  "typings": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./dist/index.mjs"
      }    
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && npx tsc -p ./tsconfig.json && mv dist/index.js dist/index.mjs",
    "prepack": "npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

The files in my solution look like this:
src
src>index.ts
src>Constants
src>Constants>Oidc.ts
src>Constants>index.ts

where the index.ts just exports all the types:
e.g. `export * from "./Oidc"`

Are there any Node/Npm legends out there who can advise what I need to do.

In the consuming app, I'd love an import statement to look something like :

`import Oidc from "pacmodpoc/Constants/Oidc"`
where that class is exported as a default export for the `Oidc.ts` file.

Thanks

Comment: If your package name is `pacmodpoc`, and you want to import something from `Constants/Oidc`, at the very least the `exports` object in `package.json` should have a key named `Constants/Oidc`. Right now you only export `.`.

Comment: I guess we need to start at the top. That bit is a nice to have. Right now, the whole thing is unconsumable. And I think some of the blogs I used must be out of date e.g. I can't even find a `typings` key in the `package.json` doco.

Comment: @onefootswill the npm docs are woefully incomplete. And TBF you can always add stuff that npm doesn't care about (e.g. typings) but other things do (in this case tsc). But since you have an exports map in your package.json, your typings key is irrelevant anyway: exports map overrides main, module, and typings keys. It's the "types" key and the other individual entries in your exports map that matter.

Comment: You probably want [something like this](https://github.com/jasmith79/sequable/blob/105978cd3bd7ae60d3bf6faef14bf2596aa47d3e/package.json#L7).

Comment: @Jared Smith They are not incomplete, everyone just keeps stacking stuff in there and expecting everyone to adopt it..

Answer (score 0):

### Typescipt and import related:

Since your project is already a Typescript project and if you want to import it into another Typescript project, you just need to reference the entry points in the `package.json`.
Why export everything in your `index.ts` if you want to import directly from other files / paths.

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "types": "./src/index.ts",
  ...
}
```

If you want to include the JS files, `types` may reference some typings, and `main` may reference the entry JS file.

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

### ES modules, Node.js and exports:

<strike>Anyway be aware that referencing ES modules might not be a good idea in a basic node setup since it uses commonjs module loading.</strike>

<strike>Getting into es modules in Node is a very deep rabit hole..
https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system</strike>

*Edit due to @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans remark:* 
True, if the importing enviornment supports ES modules go for it!

*Edit Edit due to @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans remark:* 
RIP Node 16. Use modules as you like ;)

Also the `exports` entry might be supported by node.js, but not nessesarily by Typescipt. So if you declare your exports:

```
{
  ...
  ".": {
    "require": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
    "import": "./dist/index.mjs"
  },
  "./Constants/Oidc": {
    "require": "./dist/Constants/Oidc.js",
    "types": "./dist/types/Constants/Oidc.d.ts",
    "import": "./dist/Constants/Oidc.mjs"
  }
  ...
}
```

You may require it inside the Node.js enviornment BUT if you import it in an Typescipt project, it will tell you that ic an not ind what you are looking for...

Also all exported "files" need to be declared in the `package.json`wich micht be alot of overhead.

Comment: Maybe in the past, but it definitely isn't these days? `"type": "module"` in your package file and done, your project is now a modern ESM project.

Comment: True, but might bring consequences in legacy code or enviornment. I dont know what enviornment is used in the importing project. Made a disclaimer :)

Comment: This has been the behaviour since Node 14. Which isn't even supported anymore, the oldest supported version of Node today is 18, which has zero issues with mixed ESM/CJS outside of the obvious things like `require` not existing in ESM, and needing to import CJS with `import packagename from "packagename";` =)

Comment: Oh nice ^^ Still sleepy on that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Wait but Node 16 is not at EOL or am i wrong? Oh it is since last month! https://github.com/nodejs/Release

Comment: Yep, time moves on relentlessly.

Comment: I'm using node v16.16.0 (sorry, I should have pointed that out). I'm just getting red squigglies.

Comment: Jea like i said. The export shema works within Node.js, NOT within Typescript or the JS linter / intelisense. Also if you are using Node 16 update or read the stricken through texts.